# Editing rules *************

Tags: bug

A recent poster omitted the slashes before a couple of dollar signs (that were intended as dollar signs, not transitions to math mode).  I attempted to add the slashes with an edit and was told that all edits must be at least six characters.  Fortunately, the original post included a string of asterisks I could lengthen without causing any harm.

But on a site where it might often be necessary to correct a minor TeX error, the minimum-six-character rule should go.

(And I've just been told I can't post this under the intended title because of a minimum-15-character rule for titles.  I'll add some asterisks.)

Comment: I$**$ agr$**$ee